# QGIS 3.4 Madeira crashes when calling print()

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am using the PyQGIS template from @underdark for showing the crash. Her script is running like a charm, but as soon as I add a `print("finished...")` - call in her code, QGIS 3.4 Madeira crashes.

You can look up her code on this site:
[@underdarks class template for python processing scripts](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/)

And in the following code snippet you can see the part where I added the `print()`-call:

```
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    source = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT, context)
    (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context,
                                           source.fields(), source.wkbType(), source.sourceCrs())

    features = source.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest())
    for feat in features:
        out_feat = QgsFeature()
        out_feat.setGeometry(feat.geometry())
        out_feat.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
        sink.addFeature(out_feat, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

    print("finished ...")  # QGIS3 crashes after this line
    return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
```

The crash looks like this (please note that the string "finished..." has been printed into the console before QGIS crashed):

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Don't use print in QGIS3 processing algorithms. Explanation from QGIS processing guide draft:

> Give feedback via the feedback object, not directly to QgsMessageLog
>   (and avoid print statements - these are dangerous to use for
>   algorithms which may be executed in a background thread!).

Replace print with:

```
feedback.pushInfo("finished ...")
```